# Deploying ASP.net "website" (not application) to AWS beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a ASP.net 4.0 Web Site (not a Web Application).  All the tutorials I have read discuss web applications.  I was able to get it uploaded to Beanstalk through the VS 2013 AWS addin but it doesn't work (Elastic Load Balancer xxxx has zero healthy instances.).  Is this because it's not a web application or is there something else I need to be looking in to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you by chance forget to setup a healthcheck for ELB to use?

[image]

This blog post walks you thru it: http://blog.willbeattie.net/2010/09/load-balancing-with-amazon-ec2-and.html

Comment: Great article.  I checked this and indeed it was blank.  So I set it to /home.aspx (is that good for now?).  Is there something I need to do to have it retest now that I've made the edit?  It's still listing the status as outofservice on the load balancer.

Comment: I don't think so, but make sure that loading the page you are pointing to returns a '200' response code: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html

Comment: I've been reading so much on this and still can't figure out what's wrong.  I'm sure your suggestion was a piece to the puzzle and that's now corrected.  When I try to go to the website through beanstalk, it's just a blank white page.  Any thoughts?  In the meantime I'll continue reading.

Comment: I may have found a possible issue.  When I log in to the EC2 the website is listed in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wwwroot(2) But shouldn't all the asp.net files be in C:\inetpub\ root?   I'll try to figure out how to change this.

Comment: It doesn't matter where they are, as long as you tell IIS where to find them.